# Reporting RESULTS of least square means as post-hoc test for linear mixed model- Best practice

Tags: mixed-model, reporting, lsmeans

Anybody have good example of how to report the results of a least square means result of a Linear mixed model?- I welcome any guidance on good practices to report this kind of result.

I posted below an example of outputs from lsmeans, with t1 as low temperature and t2 as high temperature and w1 as two hours of inundation.

I was thinking to report as: "For the two-hour inundation treatment, the higher-temperature treatment increased soil respiration by 14%, (p = 0.04, least square means, t ratio = -2.07)"

[image: OUtput]

[image]